# ASP.net and Javascript confirmation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have this situation:
I have an asp page that have a form and an action button. When user click button, it must show a confirmation box (confirm) to ask user. If user say OK it must do action A, and if user say Cancel it must do action B. The problem is that A,B action is on server-side and user are on client side. Because it require 2 action so I *cannot* add `return confirm()` into `onclick` attribute. So I what I've done is create a hidden field in the form and write javascript function that ask user and return value in hidden field and submit form then take action on server based on hidden field.

My question is: Is there any better design for this case?

Comment: you can do same thing by ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, at least in my opinion, it is worth taking a look at the ajax control toolkit, in particular:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_Popup.ashx

Answer (score 1):

Use two buttons in the form instead of asking after the form is submitted.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="OK">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel">
```

Only the clicked one will be successful.

Comment: This used to be one of my solution before

Answer (score 0):

Yes Ajax is the best.

You can also do via JavaScript as well using

```
location.href = newPageUrl;
```

mostly in redirection Scenario